# Unregistering RemotingConfiguration unregister well known type

Tags: remoting

How to Unregister RemotingConfiguration unregister well known type

Answer (score 1):

This might help you?

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/Advanced_Remoting.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try ChannelServices.UnregisterChannel

Answer (score 0):

I have just achieved this by:

```
RemotingServices.Disconnect(registeredTypeInstance);
```

After registering it using:

```
RemotingServices.Marshal(registeredTypeInstance, name, type);
```

see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456628/net-remoting-how-to-access-server-application-objects-from-remotable-object) for more info about RemotingService.Marshal